# A method is called on each item selected in a listbox. I need to call the method with each item progromatically,

Tags: c#, methods, foreach, listbox

A method is called on each item selected in a listbox. I need to call the method with each item in the listbox progromatically without the need to select each item. Here is the method:

```
private void btnMove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        CreateFoldersMoveFiles(); // work is performed in this method with the selected listbox text.
        if (listBox2.SelectedIndex < listBox2.Items.Count - 1)
        {
            listBox2.SelectedIndex = listBox2.SelectedIndex + 1;
        }
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it isn't part of your question, I believe you use listBox2.SelectedItem within the CreateFoldersMoveFiles method to get selected item and then process it. Instead, you need to allow CreateFoldersMoveFiles to accept an arguement and within your BtnMove_Click, loop through the listbox items and invoke the method.

```
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
{
    CreateFoldersMoveFiles(item);
}
```